# Using Python to access SQL Server SQL Database on Azure Gives an Error

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, azure, pymssql

I am trying to use the `pymssql` module in Python to access a SQL Server SQL Database. However, my code gives a traceback error when I run my code on Ubuntu Linux. BTW, the system is actually a Microsoft Azure VM.

Below is my code:

```
import pymssql

connection1 = pymssql.connect(
                server = 'redworth-test-sql.database.windows.net',
                user = '*********@redworth-test-sql',
                password = '**********',
                database = 'redworth-test-sql-database'
)

sql = connection1.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into table1 values (\'Rohit\', \'Karthik\', \'2006/08/02\')')

allRows = sql.fetchall()

print(allRows)

connection1.close()
```

(I am using a * for my username & password for security reasons, but my code on my computer has the actual strings)

(I have also installed my pymssql module on python3 using pip as well)

But running that code gives me the following error on my system:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 676, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (redworth-test-sql.database.windows.net:1433)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyMsSQL.py", line 7, in <module>
    database = 'redworth-test-sql-database'
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (redworth-test-sql.database.windows.net:1433)\n')
```

I am not sure what is causing this error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: So, you are trying to open Access database with pymssql? That's correct? If yes, then pymssql is for mssql (ms sql), which is SQL Server.

Comment: I am trying to access a SQL Server database using pymssql, not an Access one

Comment: The edit your title, from Access to access

Comment: Have you seen: [pymssql won't allow connection with specific security restrictions #535](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/535)? See also [There are several python SQL drivers available. However, Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server)

Comment: Okay, I have switched over from pymssql to pyodbc, thank you!

Comment: Hi Rohit,  does `pyodbc` work for you?

Comment: Yes, pyodbc works fine!

Comment: @RohitKarthik Congratulations the issue is solved by using `pyodbc`. I just post it as answer. You may think about mark it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations that `pyodbc` works for you.

Azure document all suggest us using `pyodbc` to connect to the Azure SQL database, bellow is the example:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Ref: [Create(Python) code to query your database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?tabs=windows#create-code-to-query-your-database).

Hope this helps.